# How can I limit the number of options that show on my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, dropdown

I'm trying to limit the number of options that these dropdown menus will show. Is there a way to do it?

```js
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://free-nba.p.rapidapi.com/teams",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "f8bbeecee3mshd11af53a602b7fcp133f59jsn3b4ffb3f20df",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "free-nba.p.rapidapi.com"}

  }).then( (response) => { 
    
    response.data.forEach ((teamObject) => {
      const teamName = teamObject.full_name;
      const teamID = teamObject.id;
      const htmlToAppend =
      `
      <option value="${teamName}">${teamName}</option>`
     
      $teamDropDown.append(htmlToAppend);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<select name="team" id="teamDropDown">
              <option value = " ">Select a team</option>
            </select>
```

these dropdown menus show but cant' seem to do it.

Comment: `forEach()` always loops over the entire array/collection/etc and can't be broken out of; I'd use a traditional for-loop instead.

Comment: Use a for loop that ends at your limit

Answer (score 1):

```
// you can modify the number of elements here
response.data.slice(0, 10).forEach ((teamObject) => {
      const teamName = teamObject.full_name;
      const teamID = teamObject.id;
      const htmlToAppend =
      `
      <option value="${teamName}">${teamName}</option>`
     
      $teamDropDown.append(htmlToAppend);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it seems to have removed all the options from the dropdown once I added .slice

Comment: Nevermind. Solved it by moving the append elsewhere further up in the code. Thanks